# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable while saving a dict

Tags: python, floating-point

I keep getting this error while trying to use pickle to save a dictionary, can anyone help?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/euan/Documents/Python/Task 1.04.py", line 31, in <module>
    change_rate()
  File "/home/euan/Documents/Python/Task 1.04.py", line 9, in change_rate
    rates.update(new_rate[old_rate])
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

My code is:

```
import pickle
rates = {"Dollar": 0.67, "Pound": 0.47, "Euro": 0.00, "Yen": 0.00}
rates = pickle.load(open("rates.dat" , "rb"))

def change_rate():
 i = input("Which exchange rate would you like to change? Dollar, Pound, Euro,Yen:")
 old_rate = rates[i]
 new_rate = float(input("Please input the new exchange rate: "))
 rates.update(new_rate[old_rate])
 pickle.dump(rates,open("rates.dat", "wb"))
 rep = input("Would you like to change another rate y/n? ")
 if rep == "y":
     change_rate()
 else:
     pass
```

Comment: So what do you expect `rates.update(new_rate[old_rate])` to do here?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to use `rates[i] = new_rate` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You make `new_rate` a `float` value, then try to treat it as an array (`new_rate[old_rate]`). Subscripting (picking one item from an array) makes no sense when applied to a float; this is precisely what the error message is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `update` to modify the dict. Just change the single entry.

```
rates[i] = new_rate
```

`new_rate` and `old_rate` are both floats, and it doesn't make sense to do a subscript on a float as you tried to do: `new_rate[old_rate]`.

Comment: @EuanWilliams of course Martijn Pieters made the same point in a comment a minute before I answered. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
rates.update(new_rate[old_rate])
```

to:

```
rates.update([(i,new_rate)])
```

if you want to use `dict.update`

simply you can do:

```
rates[i] = new_rate
```